# How to customise maven dependency version resolution?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

So I want to use maven version ranges, however the rules of the current version resolution does not fit my requirements. Is there any way, perhaps extending from the existing maven plugins, so that I can override what version from the range to be selected as the dependency version?

For example, let's say a dependency has the following range:

```
[1.0.0, 2.0.0)
```

Currently this may resolve to an unwanted version or even snapshot (there is an [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-3092) in Maven for this and still in progress)

I want to know if there is any way that I can see the list of available version candidates for the above range and then select which one I need. Is this possible with maven plugins without running the plugin directly so it resolves the dependency as part of normal build, for example:

```
mvn clean verify
```

I don't want to use maven versions plugin. We have nearly 50 microservices, we want backward compatible versions to be fetched automatically, otherwise every time a developer makes a small change, they have to run maven versions plugin against all applications.

I found `DefaultVersionRangeResolver` in maven, any hint or idea how to write my own version range resolver and include it in maven? The documentation on these stuff isn't really clear.

Thanks

Comment: What about _not_ using version ranges, but using versions maven plugin? It allows you to update your dependencies to newer versions with fine-grained parameters to allow only releases, only minor updates etc.

Comment: First which issues are you referencing to ? Furthermore you can check the [versions-maven-plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) (already suggested by @JFMeier) which can help here...and apart from that I recommend not to use versions ranges...furthermore why do you like to use them? What's the problem you are trying to solve...

Comment: I am referring to this issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-3092

Comment: I don't want to use maven versions plugin. We have nearly 50 microservices, we want the backward compatible versions to be fetched automatically, we can't go through all 50 of them and run versions plugin every time a develop make a change.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is sensible to write your own version range resolver. What you can do:

1. If you really want every minor or bugfix change automatically in the next build, you can enrich your build command, i.e. instead of `mvn clean deploy` you say `mvn versions:update-releases ... clean deploy`.
2. If your projects are tightly coupled, you can combine them to one multi-module project. Then you can build everything together and each module gets the latest changes of each other module.

If your projects are *not* tightly coupled, automatic updates may be unnecessary and might confuse developers - their build suddenly breaks because of some bug that was mystically introduced by an automatically changing component.

Comment: Thanks. We're talking about a company with huge number of applications and changing them into one multi-module project not only is easy but also requires all managements and solution architects involved. I wouldn't go for that. Multi-module projects have their own issues. Automatic update will only happen to backward compatible changes.. the developer has to add an entry to the changelog that determines their change is BC or not... so we only fetch BC changes as the version range is something like [1.0.0, 2.0.0) that means breaking changes (version 2 onwards) requires manual version change

Comment: I am myself working in a company with more than thousand Java artifacts and I know that changes take time and resources. And I understand your idea, but IMHO it does not fit into Maven philosophy. If you really want automatic minor updates, change your build command as I suggested in (1). Then you have what you want without version ranges. In our company, the developers decide if they update or not because the minor changes are often not important for everyone, but require additional testing. If you really want to write your own dependency resolution, think about using Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to answer the solution(s) I found. So we decided to start with a high version like 4.0.0 so that there is no SNAPSHOT for those versions in our maven repository. However, it seems dependency resolution for version range in maven is acting up sometimes and not reliable.

For those who still want to override maven behaviour, I found the way after digging in the maven code.

You can create a class as below:

```
@Named
@Component( role = VersionRangeResolver.class )
public class SemVerRangeResolver
    implements VersionRangeResolver, Service
{
   //The content can be copied and pasted from org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultVersionRangeResolver
}
```

Once you create this class, you need to create a file named 'components.xml' and place it in `\src\main\resources\META-INF\plexus\components.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<component-set>
  <components>
    <component>
      <role>org.eclipse.aether.impl.VersionRangeResolver</role>
      <role-hint>default</role-hint>
      <implementation>com.yourcomp.dependency.SemVerRangeResolver</implementation>
      <description />
      <isolated-realm>false</isolated-realm>
      <requirements>
        <requirement>
          <role>org.eclipse.aether.spi.log.LoggerFactory</role>
          <role-hint />
          <field-name>logger</field-name>
        </requirement>
        <requirement>
          <role>org.eclipse.aether.impl.MetadataResolver</role>
          <role-hint />
          <field-name>metadataResolver</field-name>
        </requirement>
        <requirement>
          <role>org.eclipse.aether.impl.SyncContextFactory</role>
          <role-hint />
          <field-name>syncContextFactory</field-name>
        </requirement>
        <requirement>
          <role>org.eclipse.aether.impl.RepositoryEventDispatcher</role>
          <role-hint />
          <field-name>repositoryEventDispatcher</field-name>
        </requirement>
      </requirements>
    </component>
  </components>
</component-set>
```

then create a jar file and drop it in your `{MAVEN_HOME}/lib/ext`

This will override the default maven range dependency resolver and you can make any change the rules to apply semver rules